# What is thetaStart and thetaLength?

Tags: geometry, three.js

In Three.js's CircleGeometry class there are the parametres thetaStart and thetaLength. As far as I can tell they make the circle crinkled. What are they for and how do they work?

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/CircleGeometry.js

Comment: Looks like they make circle segments

Comment: Yes, thetaStart - start angle, thetaLength - finish angle. Circle is `thetaStart = 0`;  `thetaLength = Math.PI * 2`;

Comment: @uhura: not finish angle, but difference between start and finish angle. So modifying `thetaStart` only will rotate the arc but preserve its length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These parameters can be used to describe a circle arc. The defaults are `thetaStart`=0 and `thetaLength`=2π, so they form a whole circle. A smaller value for `thetaLength` will describe only part of a circle, and you can use `thetaStart` to define the angle where that segment starts.

Comment: Ah I see, I noticed they changed the segments but could not see a reason. Arcs make sense! Thanks :)